# When reviewing, indicate if a user has multiple answers on this question

Tags: feature-request, review, multiple-answers

Just now, I came across these two answer in review, in this order.

1. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/133351
2. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/133349

As you can see, the same (unregistered) user posted more or less the same answer twice, probably in an attempt to correct their first one.

I came across the second one first, which I edited and approved.

I then was presented with their first answer. At first I thought another user had been copying content, so I went to the question to check and that is when I noticed what had happened.

**When reviewing, can we please get an indication that a user has another answer on the same question?**

If not, can we at least get answers to the same question in chronological order?

Comment: The order in review tends to show newer first. IIRC the reviews are put in buckets and when you click next one of the buckets is selected to pick a review from. Chronological order will be hard to achieve. The other requirement is something that is doable with a userscript. Let's see if someone takes that on in 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: I think SOUP already shows *all* answers when the user is on review queue. Alternatively, if I'm not on my personal PC, I'll open the Q&A first to check for the whole thread (yes, time consuming, but it's fine for me)

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. your _personal_ Personal Computer? ;)

Comment: @SQB yeah, not my *work* PC :p